# Probability of outcomes in numerology (history)

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, math-history, symmetry

I was reading some books about the history of mathematics and there is always a chapter on Pythagoreans and their mysticism. One thing I did not know was that there was and still a process called gematria that is about using a mapping of characters of the language to numbers and summing the corresponding number of words in an attempt to convey secret meanings in messages e.g Bible or show association between words/sentences in some manner.
I don't understand how this originated or remained but I was curious on the last part i.e. showing associations.
I think it is trivial in general to show correlation between sentences due to just trying to preserve symmetry.
What I am not sure an my question is about is the following:
If we come up with some very meaningful association eg

"Energy = X"
"Mass times light speed squared =X"
where X is the number of the sum or "Euler times one hundred" having the sum 271 how can we calculate the probability of something like that occuring?
I think due to the large number of words and using sum it is very probable to be able to find such types of equalities.
But how would we calculate it?

Comment: There are finitely many english words. Since arbitrary chains of letters are not necessarily words (and most aren’t) it would best to leave this computation to a computer.

Comment: Very small probability, for sure.

Comment: @William: I wouldn't need to compute it though. Just calculate a number for some sentence and the try to construct the equivalent I want by picking the right words or even messing up the syntax a bit

Comment: @JeanMarie: i would think it is not small at all due to the reason i mention in the comment above. I am not asking some algorithm. I think the reason that historically this was sustained was basically to such tricks and I am trying to check the probability in general of being able to find such "convincing associations"

Comment: If you don't just use trial and error with human intuition (perhaps aided by a program helpfully supplying dictionary words of the number you need), then it seems like you'd want a semantics-aware AI to help you search.

Comment: @MarkS.: Actually I don't want to find such instances automatically at all. I am pretty sure I can produce any equality I want by fidlling around with the phrasing and keeping the symmetry i.e same gematria. What I was curious is if we can estimate somehow to what degree we can up with so "meaningful" associations that would explain how this process persisted for thousands of years till today as I have understood

Comment: I guess, perhaps due to a lack of imagination, I can't think of a better way to get at the probability/degree to which it can be done across the board without having someone attempt thousands of new examples - ideally a computer.

Comment: @MarkS.: Fair enough. I was thinking that the key might be that we use the sum of a very small set of characters i.e ~24-30 and due to the huge number of words we end up with a huge amount of collisions but I don't know how to formulate it. Perhaps some approximation/guestimation of number of words of a language, number of characters per word, frequency of characters in words of the language('e' is most frequent in english) number of possible permutations that create phrases that could be considered complete and the number of possible sums. Somehow all these combined show a hint already.